# Flutter App with only one screen that can showup even ehrn phone is locked

Tags: flutter

Im making an app with multiple screens(stateful widgets) and able to navigate between them, but now I want one of those screens to open even when phone is locked, when I receive some data from server, or a trigger from server, I want to open that screen on the phone even when its locked

I tried adding the following attributes in AndroidManifest.xml

`android:showWhenLocked="true" android:turnScreenOn="true"`

I use fullscreen Intent notifications which is a trigger for the notification now.

this applies to the whole app, and also if I lock the phone while using the app, and try to unlock, the screen opens without asking pin or pattern, which I believe is because we mentioend in attributes

I also tried creating/adding one more activity element into this AndroindManifest file but no luck

I need the whole app to be behind the phone lock, but except the one specific screen in the app, that one screen must be able to open in any locked device,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.